# No-IP + extenal IP not even pinged

Tags: ssh, dns, ping, port-forwarding

I set up my RPi using no-ip with this [video](http://www.pibeginners.com/dynamicdns/). Locally I can access SSH at port 22 as normal. But when using my external IP or my NOIP from a mobile connected to 3g with the 22 port forwarded it does nothing. I tried to ping it, both external and NOIP but I have 100% loss of packets. 
Using the [port checker tool](http://www.portchecktool.com/) I saw that port 22 is open.
I use also the weaved which works fine.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Is port 22 open internally or externally?  Are you sure you got the internal IP address correct in the port forward?  and finally if you manually resolve your noip sub-domain name do you get the same IP as your external IP?

Comment: I reformatted raspbian and I configured the NOIP in the router options and now it works (so far).